# Container Elements

Tags: html, css

So, I'm designing my personal portfolio and everything goes well. However when I enter the responsive view, my containers within my body section are moving yet I want them be static or fixed while on responsive mode.

I have attached the css styles applied to my global container and body.

```css
/*Global-styling*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #fff3d9;
  font-family: "helvetica";
}

:before,
:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

I have additionally added a link of my site you can check how it behaves on responsive mode. Kindly assist

[https://zealous-jepsen-358c52.netlify.app]

Comment: The layout will only change if you apply a `media-query` in your CSS. If your layout changes when you change the window size then you need to take a look at your media queries, and you've not included those in your question.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).